# Understanding getlogin spoofing

Tags: linux, security, su, privileges

My question is in three (or so) related parts:

1) My understanding is that `getlogin()` will effectively return the `auid` associated with the process and so isn't actually changable by the user. Is that understanding true?

2) I found [this old exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/22781/) regarding `getlogin()` used in pam_wheel. I'm familiar with each individual command but not sure I understand how they're accomplishing the end effect. It seems they're accepting input from a symlink called `tty1` which is also the same tty name the root user is on. How is it that the symlink succeeded? Shouldn't /dev/tty1 already be there if `root` is shown as being logged into it (in utmp)?

3) I was just starting out with GNU/Linux (like abut a year or so into it) when this exploit was written up, so it's possible that I'm unaware of some previous iteration in Linux identity/privilege management. How could a normal user create that symlink? I know `/dev` was a static list of `mknod` files back then, but reads/writes on symlinks get evaluated by the hardlink referenced, correct? I realize this is on a udev-based `/dev` hierarchy, but by way of example this is one pty on one of my systems:

```
crw--w----. 1 jadavis6 tty 136, 3 May 27 00:47 /dev/pts/3
```

Shouldn't the above prevent any user that's not `jadavis6` nor in the `tty` group access (via symlink or otherwise) for reading or writing? Were the permissions in `/dev` more liberal pre-`devfs`/`udev`?

Also, how does reading from the TTY grant the process you're currently in root access? I could see using it to spy on the remote session by reading everything written to the tty device, but how are they getting `logname` to change for them? Are the subsequent commands (after the redirect from tty1) just what is happening on the root console or is there something at play here that actually led to this be a way to get root? If it's the latter, is this exploit really `su` specific? I mean won't a lot of functionality be opened up if all you have to do is create a symlink to a device file and then your `auid` is now root?

**Answer:**
Found out most of the critical information above in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78217/understanding-getlogin/78229#78229)